# Gunicorn Websocket Worker not using SCRIPT_NAME env

Tags: apache, websocket, gunicorn

I'm trying to run the gunicorn-websockets worker on the command line with `gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 --threads 20 wsgi:app -b 0.0.0.0:5000 --env SCRIPT_NAME=/asdf`

However under `ip:5000/asdf`, I get a 404 error and unable to reach my webpage. However under `ip:5000`, I'm able to reach it.

If I use the regular `gevent` worker, as I'm able to reach the `ip:5000/asdf` using SCRIPT_NAME. However, I need to work with websockets, and use the `SCRIPT_NAME`, but it seems gevent-websockets worker is unable to use SCRIPT_NAME.

Relevant Apache.conf section (`asdf/ws` is where the websocket is)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/asdf/ws [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P,L]

<Location /asdf>
        SSLRequireSSL
        ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:5000/asdf
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:5000/asdf
        RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL ssl
        RequestHeader set X-FORWARDED-SSL on
</Location>
```

I'm able to connect under `/asdf` through gevent, but on my websocket protocol I get `RuntimeError: You need to use the gevent-websocket server. See the Deployment section of the documentation for more information.` error, which is expected - and I fall back on transport.

However I want to connect under '/asdf' with the websocket worker, and it doesn't work. I also need to use SCRIPT_NAME.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I gave up and just used eventlet. Though I would love to know why gevent-websocket doesn't work.